# Как реализовать правильно функцию чтения и разделения?

Tags: python

Всем привет. Что то совсем запутался с реализацией кода

```
import io


def separator(argument):
    return '.\n'.join(argument.split('. '))


with io.open(r'C:\dset\test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        print(separator('НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - ' + str(num) + ' - ' + line.strip()))
```

Данный код показыват это

```
НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 1 - Мы ехали в музей.
Они пили малако.
Есть один пример.
 лаг был еще целый.
```

А мне нужно что бы прописалось и про нумеровалось каждое предложение вот так:

```
НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 1 - Мы ехали в музей.
НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 2 - Они пили малако.
НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 3 - Есть один пример.
НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 4 -  лаг был еще целый.
```

Comment: У тебя в test.txt текст записан одной строкой, вот ты и получаешь только 1.

Comment: @Эникейщик так правильно я хочу функцией разбить его на предложения и потом показать их с подписью и нумерацией построчно

Comment: так нужно сначала разбить на предложения, а потом нумеровать. enumerate получает ОДНУ строку, одна строка идет в separator, и одна же строк выводится. И вставляя в строку "\n" ты не увеличиваешь количество строк. Их так же остается одна.

Comment: @Эникейщик хорошо, я туго сооброжаю, Вы не могли бы показать это кодом?

Comment: мог бы, но не буду. Сначала нужно разделить по точкам, и без всяких join. Получится список предложений. Этот список нужно передавать в enumerate вместо file. Функция separator вообще не нужна.

Comment: @Эникейщик так если я что то разделю по точкам без ф-ции сепоратора, получиться некорректный вывод предложений они будут представлены списком и не будут завершаться на точку

Comment: ну просто добавить точку при выводе и все.

Comment: @Эникейщик а потом я начну билиоекой pyenchant исправлять ошибки в словах и удалять лишние символы, что мне делать потом в этом случае?

Comment: какие лишние символы и какое отношение исправление ошибок имеет к этому вопросу? Никакого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = 'Мы ехали в музей. Они пили малако. Есть один пример. лаг был еще целый.'
print(*(f'НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - {num} - {line.strip()}.' 
        for num, line in enumerate(file.split('.'), 1) if line), 
      sep='\n')

НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 1 - Мы ехали в музей.
НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 2 - Они пили малако.
НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 3 - Есть один пример.
НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ - 4 - лаг был еще целый.
```